# Can't change directory of the saved screenshots

Tags: 20.04, screenshot

I have accidently deleted my Pictures folder and then I have restored it.But now the screenshots are being saved in /home/Screenshots instead of/home/Pictures/Screenshots.I have tried multiple methods.Installed the gnome screenshots extensions,changed the directory but nothing has happened.Please help me.

Comment: [edit] your question to indicate which screenshot tool you are using.

Comment: I am using the default screenshot tool.

Comment: install and run dconf editor using this reference  https://aamnah.com/ubuntu/change-default-screenshot-save-location